# Team City .NET Duplicates Finder Build Runner via MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I have been at this for a couple of hours now and its beginning to do my head in.

Within TeamCity am trying to get an MSBuild to run the .NET Duplicates Finder, this was the easy bit.

```
<Target Name="Duplication" DependsOnTargets="CreateSVNStats">
<MakeDir Directories="$(BuildDir)\test\" Condition="!Exists('$(BuildDir)\test')"  />
    <Exec Command="&quot;C:\buildAgent\plugins\dotnet-dupfinder\bin\dupfinder.exe&quot; --show-stats --show-text --discard-cost=70 -i **/*.vb -o $(BuildDir)\test\result.xml" ContinueOnError="false"/>
</Target>
```

I have the result.xml that this what am stuck on is getting the result.xml to be displayed in teamcity.

I have tried to add a custom tab with the result.xml in it and it doesn't work.

was wondering if anyone knew where the .NET Duplicates Finder Build Runner xlst is so i can format the Result.xml file correctly and display it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any ideas about formatting the result.xml file but can you upgrade to TeamCity 6? With TC6 you can use multiple build steps, e.g. run your build using msbuild then run a Duplicates Finder (.Net), the results will both be displayed under the same build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Team City 8 comes with built in duplicate finder: [http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Duplicates+Finder+(.NET)](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Duplicates+Finder+%28.NET%29)

Might be available in earlier versions too, haven't checked.